# abi::__dynamic_cast returns nullptr for upcasts

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, abi

I need to hook into C++'s exception throwing mechanism like this:

```
namespace __cxxabiv1
{
    extern "C" void __cxa_throw(void* voidPointerToActualObject, std::type_info* stdTypeInfoOfActualObject, void (*destructor)(void *))
    {
        // If thrownException is a custom exception type or something deriving from it, poke a value into it.
    }
}
```

[If you're wondering "Why would you do that?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73884165/4242201)

I have this simple example of throwing an exception that's part of a very simple class hierarchy:

```
#include <stdexcept>

class Upper : public std::exception
{
    public:
        int pokeMe = 111111;
};
class Lower : public Upper {};

int main()
{
    throw Lower();
}

#include <cxxabi.h>

namespace __cxxabiv1
{
    extern "C" void __cxa_throw(void* voidPointerToActualObject, std::type_info* stdTypeInfoOfActualObject, void (*destructor)(void *))
    {
        // The point is to do the equivalent of this:
        Lower* staticallyTypedPointerToActualObject = reinterpret_cast<Lower*>(voidPointerToActualObject);
        auto thisWorks = dynamic_cast<Upper*>(staticallyTypedPointerToActualObject);
        thisWorks->pokeMe = 222222;

        // But we don't know the actual static type, so we can't get a statically typed pointer. We only have a void* and a type_info:
        auto abiTypeInfoOfActualObject = dynamic_cast<const abi::__class_type_info*>(stdTypeInfoOfActualObject);
        auto abiTypeInfoOfUpper = dynamic_cast<const abi::__class_type_info*>(&typeid(Upper));
        Upper* thisDoesNotWork = reinterpret_cast<Upper*>(abi::__dynamic_cast(voidPointerToActualObject, abiTypeInfoOfActualObject, abiTypeInfoOfUpper, -1));
        thisDoesNotWork->pokeMe = 333333;

        // Elided for clarity: Call the original __cxa_throw function here
        // Instead, suppress these warnings:
        (void)destructor; // Unused parameter
        while (1) { } // Return from non-returning function
    }
}
```

I don't see a reason why `__dynamic_cast` shouldn't be able to upcast, but it returns `nullptr`.
Why? And how do I get it to work?

It seems to be able to do downcasts just fine, BTW:

```
auto abiTypeInfoOfActualObject = dynamic_cast<const abi::__class_type_info*>(&typeid(Upper)); // Plonking this here for testing
auto abiTypeInfoOfUpper = dynamic_cast<const abi::__class_type_info*>(&typeid(Lower)); // Casting to Lower instead of Upper
Lower* thisDoesNotWork = reinterpret_cast<Lower*>(abi::__dynamic_cast(voidPointerToActualObject, abiTypeInfoOfActualObject, abiTypeInfoOfUpper, -1));
```

Comment: Why can't the hooked `__cxa_throw` use the normal `dynamic_cast`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `dynamic_cast<T>(x)` requires that the static type of x is a pointer to a class type that "somehow relates to `T`". But voidPointerToActualObject is a `void*`. I can `reinterpret_cast` that to `Lower*` in my example because I know for a fact that I throw that. But a program could throw a number of different things that don't relate to `Lower` or `Upper`. E.g. `throw "NotEvenAnException";`.

Comment: [This](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#dynamic_cast-algorithm) suggests that `abi::__dynamic_cast` only implements base-to-derived cast and cross-cast. It doesn't expect to be called for a derived-to-base cast because the compiler is assumed to have resolved this cast at compile time, by effectively replacing it with `static_cast`.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to dig up [this archived conversation from 2004](https://github.com/itanium-cxx-abi/cxx-abi/blob/79d8186fdd2d91259249e71ef2e352383eaa5304/cxx-abi-dev/archives/2004-February.txt#L486):

> The ABI document does not require that __dynamic_cast perform a
> derived-to-base cast.  Those __dynamic_cast operations that can
> actually  be performed statically by the compiler must be performed
> statically by  the compiler -- the runtime library does not expect to
> be called in that  situation.

So that answers that question. Greeeeeeat.
But the conversation luckily mentions:

> Yes; the holder knows the static type; it can throw a pointer of that
> type.  The cast operation can catch the pointer type it's looking for,
> or fail the cast with catch(...).

That gave me the idea to try this (simplified version):

```
namespace __cxxabiv1
{

    using ThrowFunction = decltype(__cxa_throw)*;
    ThrowFunction oldThrowFunction = nullptr;

    extern "C" void __cxa_throw(void* voidPointerToActualObject, std::type_info* stdTypeInfoOfActualObject, void (*destructor)(void *))
    {
        if (oldThrowFunction == nullptr)
        {
            oldThrowFunction = (ThrowFunction)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "__cxa_throw");
        }

        try
        {
            oldThrowFunction(voidPointerToActualObject, stdTypeInfoOfActualObject, destructor);
        }
        catch (Upper& ex)
        {
            ex.pokeMe = 333333;
        }
        catch (...)
        {
        }

        oldThrowFunction(voidPointerToActualObject, stdTypeInfoOfActualObject, destructor);
    }
}
```

And I can't believe it but it actually works!

Edit: Disclaimer: It seems that this way, the destructor callback is actually called twice, because if use `std::string pokeMe`, the string is trashed by the time I get to the second call to oldThrowFunction. I'll experiment around with over the next few days.

Edit2: That's indeed the case. I couldn't find anything indicating whether `__cxa_throw` accepts `nullptr` as the destructor argument (it didn't crash for me, at least), so the safest bet is to pass a pointer to an empty dummy function:

```
void dummyDestructor(void*)
{
}
//...
oldThrowFunction(voidPointerToActualObject, stdTypeInfoOfActualObject, &dummyDestructor);
```

Edit 3: Goddamnit! It seems that this causes memory corruption. `malloc` crashes with a segfault at a later point when doing this.
Back to square -5.

Comment: Perhaps rethrow using `throw;` or `std::rethrow_exception`? And to avoid infinite recursion, add a global flag (possibly thread_local) to see if you're rethrowing or not.

Comment: `throw;` wouldn't work because that only works in a catch block. `std::rethrow_exception` needs an `std::exception_ptr`. I can probably create that from the `void*`. I'll test it when I have the time and report back.

Comment: But you do have a catch block.

Comment: Right now, yes. But see Edit 3. This approach of throwing with `oldThrowFunction` and immediately catching it to see if it's the right type, then throwing it again with `oldThrowFunction`, seems to corrupt memory. That's why I need to replace this approach. I assumed you were suggesting a replacement. Is that not the case?

Comment: Yes, I'm saying that instead of the second `oldThrowFunction`, you use `throw`, which in turn calls your `__cxa_throw`, which calls `oldThrowFunction`. This way you have one `oldThrowFunction` per one `__cxa_throw`, which might fix memory corruption.

Comment: I see. You want to replace the second call, not the first one. It's a bit ugly that I'll have to add `throw;` to every diagnostic catch block, but at this point I don't even care anymore. I'll try that too.